# Rubymotion / Simple geolocation with bubblewrap

Tags: geolocation, rubymotion

Quite surprised to get the following error :

```
undefined method `[]' for #<CLLocation:0x9a95cd0> (NoMethodError)
```

when trying to reproduce the simplest example given :

```
  BW::Location.get_once do |result|
    p "From Lat #{result[:from].latitude}, Long #{result[:from].longitude}"
    p "To Lat #{result[:to].latitude}, Long #{result[:to].longitude}"
  end
```

CLLocation is imported (even if not sure it is required while using bubbblewrap) using the following :

```
app.frameworks += ["CoreLocation"]
```

as bubblewrap location is :

```
require 'bubble-wrap/location'
```

Any obviousness appreciated (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BW::Location.get_once` yields a `CLLocation` object, not an array of `CLLocation`.

Try something like this:

```
BW::Location.get_once do |location|
    p "Lat #{location.latitude}, Long #{location.longitude}"
end
```

Comment: And maybe you also experienced it ?! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530828/rubymotion-bubblewrap-geolocation-in-airplane-mode-makes-the-app-crash

Comment: How about displaying a pin on map with that location?