# Rubymotion / bubblewrap geolocation in airplane mode makes the app crash

Tags: ruby, geolocation, rubymotion

Trying to get an clean geoloc implementation in some app;
quite struggling with the limitations of what bubblewrap provide for locations

```
   def get_location
        begin
          BW::Location.get_once do |location|
            if location
              self.latitude   = location.latitude
              self.longitude  = location.longitude
            end
          end
        rescue
          puts "can't geoloc"
        end
      end
```

With this code (sorry bu I show the 'tests' that - i expect - would work as fallbacks with ruby code), I just get a plain app crash if i set the airplane mode on the phone

Thanks if any experiences on making it works in this mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the geolocation stuff runs in a separate thread, so you would want to put your begin/rescue code within the block:

```
BW::Location.get_once do |location|
  begin
    if location
      self.latitude   = location.latitude
      self.longitude  = location.longitude
    end
  rescue
    puts "can't geoloc"
  end
end
```

However, Bubblewrap will actually let you know if there was an error by setting `location` to a hash with one value, `{error: type}`. Since you're using `get_once`, the return value could be either a `Hash` or a `CLLocation` object, so you do need to check the object type to avoid an error:

```
BW::Location.get_once do |location|
  if location.is_a?(Hash) && location[:error]
    puts "can't geoloc"
  else
    self.latitude   = location.latitude
    self.longitude  = location.longitude
  end
end
```